# Fade In/Out an array elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I fade In and Fade Out array elements? I have got a following array with three elements in the JavaScript and want to Fade them In xor Out one by one with few seconds delay.

```
textlist = new Array( "news1", "news2","news3");
```

**Update:** Array items are not id's, these are actual text appearing on the website.

Comment: @RobW. it's most probably [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10353672/601179) that he wants.

Comment: @RobW. I was wrong... it's "do it all for me" kind of question. **-1**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you said the array items are text; So you need to show somewhere in you page, e.g in a `<div id='newsPanel'/>` element.
You may try:

```
var listTicker = function(options) {

    var defaults = {
        list: [],
        startIndex:0,
        interval: 3 * 1000,
    }   
    var options = $.extend(defaults, options);

    var listTickerInner = function(index) {

        if (options.list.length == 0) return;

        if (!index || index < 0 || index > options.list.length) index = 0;

        var value= options.list[index];

        options.trickerPanel.fadeOut(function() {
            $(this).html(value).fadeIn();
        });

        var nextIndex = (index + 1) % options.list.length;

        setTimeout(function() {
            listTickerInner(nextIndex);
        }, options.interval);

    };

    listTickerInner(options.startIndex);
}

var textlist = new Array("news1", "news2", "news3");

$(function() {
    listTicker({
        list: textlist ,
        startIndex:0,
        trickerPanel: $('#newsPanel'),
        interval: 3 * 1000,
    });
});​
```

Try this at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kibria/Lsy77/1/).

Comment: Positions of surrounding elements of the 'newsPanel' might be affected, if the  the 'newsPanel' element has no fixed 'width' & 'height', or it is an inline (<span>) element, and since the text contents could be of different sizes.

Comment: It was becuase of IE 8, In IE7 it is rendering okay.

Answer (score 3):

If the strings are the elements ids:

```
textlist = ["news1", "news2","news3"];
$.each(textlist, function(index, value){
    $('#' + value).delay(1000 * index).fadeIn();
});
```

- The first element fades in after 1000 * 0 = right away
- The second element fades in after 1000 * 1 = One second.
- The third element fades in after 1000 * 2 = Two seconds.
- ...
- ...
- The **n** element fades in after 1000 * n = **n** seconds.

[**Live DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/RwMy7/2/)

---

**Update:**

O.K. you updated that the elements in the array are not the `id`s but a free text, so you can use the `:contains` selector:

```
textlist = ["News 1", "News 2", "News 3"];
$.each(textlist, function(index, value) {
    $(':contains("' + value + '")').delay(1000 * index).fadeIn();
});​
```

[**Live DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/RwMy7/4/)

Comment: The array to iterate over is missing from the snippet

Comment: Array elements are not id's, these are actual text appearing on the website

Comment: @user1263981. O.k. I updated the answer. next time give all the information at the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

I presume those values are ID of an element. If so try something like below,

```
function fadeInOut(textlist) {
    $('#' + textlist.splice(0, 1)[0]).fadeIn(1000, function() {
        $(this).fadeOut(1000, function() {
            fadeInOut(textlist);
        });
    });
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/RwMy7/1/)

Comment: Array elements are not id's, these are actual text appearing on the website. I am trying to create a news ticker like BBC .

Answer (score 0):

**HTML :**

```
<div id="container"></div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
var textlist=new Array( "news1", "news2","news3");
var timer;

    function textFade(index){
       $("#container").fadeOut(200).html(text).fadeIn(200);
        timer = setTimeout(function() {
            textFade(text);

             },3000);
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
        textFade(0);
    });
```

Comment: @user1263981 , I've edited the code, I'm sorry about the erroneous code provided earlier.

Comment: @user1263981. Can you give us a fiddle with what the result should look like? we are shooting in the dark!

Comment: Hello gordon, I THINK he wants to cycle through an array of text. That's what I understood and that's the solution I have provided.

Comment: you need to use the `@` prefix to inform me. anyway I feel like we're doing all the job for him, that's not the way it should be. I quite.

Comment: Hi guys, I should have made it more clear as it is confusing few people. I am trying to make a bbc style news ticker. Thanks for the help.

Comment: i would also want to mark Kibria answer's as accepted but don't know if i can mark two answers as correct

Comment: @user1263981 oh, so that happened because you unmarked mine, just wanted to know what happened :)

Comment: It doesn't fadeIn the same text instead it FadeIn the next text and then fade it out. But its not your fault as i didn't explain the my requirement in details.

Comment: @user1263981 Since you've already got the answer, no probs :). Otherwise, if you want the text you are passing to the function to fadein/fadeout , I'm updating the answer.